# Storing usernames and passwords in separate databases

Tags: database, security, passwords, microservices

Im currently in the early stages of engineering a system that utilises a microservices architecture.

I'm at the point where I'm implementing a user login system. I had the idea to have one service that handles all insensitive user information (e.g. username, email, age etc) and then have another service that handles passwords (e.g. storing them, encryption, verification etc).

Having this architecture would mean that user data and passwords would be stored in two completely seperate databases.

I think this is a feasible approach and could improve security.

Is this approach overkill? Obviously I am going to be salting and hashing passwords but having these stored completely seperately gives another level of security.

Are there any drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 1):

This approach with storing the credentials in a separate database can indeed make your application more secure. It really depends on how it is implemented, and what privileges an attacker can get.

One example is SQL-injection, it can be difficult to make your whole application bullet proof, but it is easy to make the only request to get the credentials safe. Usually an attacker can get the credentials whenever (s)he finds a leak, not so if the credentials are stored in a separate database.

If the attacker has privileges on the server, there may be no advantage, but I cannot see any drawbacks neither.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to improve security I would advice against building your own user login system. However, I think it is a good idea to separate the authentication/authorization from the profiles.

Comment: Whats an alternative to building my own? I dont want to use OAuth2 and a larger providers system.